# In-App Purchase feature in codenameone app

Tags: in-app-purchase, codenameone

i'm new in mobile app.

I am developing an app in CodeNameOne.
I created a flow-chart to describe it.

is it possible to implement it in codenameone?
does google & apple support to query on purchased items by invoices id?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See these about IAP in Codename One:
http://mobilecodetogo.blogspot.co.il/2013/02/in-app-purchase-in-ios-with-codenameone.html
http://mobilecodetogo.blogspot.co.il/2013/03/android-does-it-better-in-app-purchase.html

Normally the products need to be listed in the client side since listing isn't a very cross platform feature so you need to have the product id's on your side.